# Append elements to List<String, String>

Tags: java, string, collections

I have a `List` object called `listAdd` declared as:

```
List<Check<String, String>> listAdd = new ArrayList<Check<String, String>>();
```

I have the below code that retrieves a `String` from one `List`, and another `String` from another `List`:

```
for (list1<String, String> h : list1_a) {
    for (list2<String, String> s : list2_a) {
        if (condition) { 
            //add h.getString, s.getString to listAdd
        }
    }
}
```

How can I add the strings obtained from `s` and `h` to `listAdd`?

Comment: Can you provide the `Check<T, V>` source ?

Comment: listAdd.add(new Check<String, String>(h.getString(), s.getStrng()));

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
listAdd.add(new Check(h.getString(),s.getString()));
```

I presume that your `Check` object has a constructor that takes two strings.